# How to show excerpt field

Tags: excerpt

My excerpt field has vanished on the back-end of WordPress posts. Even when ticked in "screen options" it does not display. There's nothing in my functions.php that would override it... So is there something elsewhere in WordPress that might stop it showing up?

Comment: I've changed theme, and disabled all plug-ins, and it's still not showing up :/

Answer (score 0):

Try to using this in your function.php file and let me know if any query

```
add_post_type_support( 'page', 'excerpt' );
```

Comment: Hi Pratik - that doesn't work I'm afraid... (I think the codex says that only works if "excerpt" is not showing in "screen options", and it is.

Comment: Right. No. I'm just being foolish. It was showing up, just miles down at the bottom of the page. Thanks for your help though!

Comment: If this answer is useful for u so please mark as a accepted answer.Thanks!